# Comma grammatical function

Tags: commas, comma-splices, parenthetical-commas

Could someone please name the grammatical comma use in the sentence below? It looks like an interrupter (parenthetical), but I'm unsure if the usage is correct.

"The title of the song “This is America” stays true to what Gambino is trying to convey throughout the video about the culture who would record or share something rather than help, and how as a society, we are teaching the younger generations to accept this way of life too."

Comment: If you put a comma after 'society' then you also need one before 'as a'.

Comment: Which specific comma are you talking about? The sentence has two of them. (But the previous comment is correct. It's difficult to evaluate what's currently there when there should be at least one more or one less.)